# Retrieve Response body as plain text or xml in Angularjs 2 HTTP GET request

Tags: xml, angular, typescript

I am trying to make `get` request to server which returns XML:

```
let text = "";
this.http.get('http://example.com', {headers : headers})
     .map((res:Response) => res.text()).subscribe(data => text = data);
```

But, `text` variable is empty string, how can I retrieve plain text to convert to XML or how can I directly get XML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me, maybe you are trying to access `text` before http call is finished? Have in mind that http calls are asynchronous operations. Try this out and you will see that it works perfectly:

```
let text = "";
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.map((res:Response) => res.text())
.subscribe(
    data => {
        text = data;
        console.log(text);
     });
```

Comment: that's was the issue , when i was accessing `text` value after that piece of code. it was not already done and that's why it was empty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good. Try like this

```
this.http.get('http://example.com', {headers : headers})
     .map((res:Response) => { return res.text() }).subscribe(data =>  {text = data});
```

Comment: it's the same , text is empty

Comment: did you confirm on network tab that responses body is containing any text? This piece of code is all good as it is.

Comment: you shouldnt put a return in the `.map()`, and you shouldnt put the subscribe directly on the `.map()`